# Blackberry Development - UI design

Tags: blackberry

Is anyway to develop black berry apps with drag and drop IDE (interface builder) that is similiar to windows mobile development or android?

I can use either visual studio or eclipse.

Are there any other smartphone development such as those 2 that support drag and drop UI building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the [Visual Studio RAD plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/rapidappdev/) has some sort of drag and drop interface.

I wouldn't recommend this tho as it gives you very little control over your UI, RIM are stopping support for it shortly (sorry, can't find the article where I read this).

As far as I know there isn't anything else, you'd be best to read the tutorials on RIM's site and trying to create something from that.

Here is a link to a [similar question](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Is-there-any-drag-and-drop-tool-for-blackberry-application/td-p/356036;jsessionid=42311E40D22A31CCAB57052DA46EA432) asked on the Blackberry support forum.

Comment: RIM's end of life notice for Visual Studio Plugin:

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/rapidappdev/eolnotice.jsp

Comment: The visual studio plug-in didn't integrate properly with my version of VS. I am not sure of the reason as yet, but I had to reinstall SP1 for Visual studio to get it to work properly again.

Answer (score 0):

but hey! I found the answers for you....
We use an IDE called SmartFace App Studio... it's similar to Eclipse I guess.
But well, it's nice to have the Emulator runs smooth after finishing drag & dropping the UI elements there.

if you want to have it try to get it here...
http://www.mobinex.biz/sas/